# Mysql Return Duplicates Of Certain Field With Full Row

Tags: mysql, select, duplicates

I would like to have a mysql select query that will select all from a table and also include a count of duplicates that exist in the table for a specific field. Here is a table and the results I would like.

```
TestTable
    Id        Name        Dogs
    1         Eric        1
    2         Dave        2
    3         Chris       4
    4         Eric        3
```

I would like to have the following results returned, based on a search for records that have duplicate names.

```
    Id        Name        Dogs
    1         Eric        1
    4         Eric        3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
where name in
(
    select name
    from your_table
    group by name
    having count(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SELECT 
a.Id,a.Name,a.Dogs,
(SELECT count(b.Name) 
FROM TestTable b 
WHERE b.Name=a.Name) as totcount
FROM TestTable a GROUP By a.Name;
```

This will work.